# How do we get the parent tab URL of the current chrome tab?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tabs

On my application home page, there is a link which opens a new tab when clicked.

After some research, I found below code which gets triggered when a new chrome tab is launched. The "active_tab" object below gives information about the current tab.

But how do we get the Parent tab URL (previous active tab) here ? Please help.

I need to get my Home page url here from which this active_tab is launched.

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {  
  chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function(active_tab){

      alert(active_tab.url);          

      /* code */

   });
});
```

Comment: Use [openerTabId](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) property.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks @wOxxOm.

Used the openerTabId property to get parent tab.

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {  
    chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function(active_tab){
        chrome.tabs.get(active_tab.openerTabId, function(parent_tab){             
            alert(parent_tab.url);            
        });     
    });
});
```