# In a Chrome Extension, how can I get the parent (or opener) tab of a new window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

If I right click a link and open it in a new tab, I can get the "openerTabId" as described in [How do we get the parent tab URL of the current chrome tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43990584/how-do-we-get-the-parent-tab-url-of-the-current-chrome-tab).

But how can I get the parent tab if I open a link in a new window?  I have tried:

**chrome.windows.onCreated** - the callback's parameter is a [Window](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#type-Window) which has no information about the parent.  A Window *can* have an array of tabs - I expected the newly opened Window to have a one-element tabs array (and that the tab would have an openerTabId), but this is optional and my Window does not have a tabs property (why not?).

**chrome.tabs.onCreated** - this is also triggered when the new window is created, but there is no openerTabId property on the [Tab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) that is passed to my callback.

**chrome.tabs.onActivated** - i.e. using the same method that works when the link is opened in a new tab in the same window.  Same problem as above: I get the active tab id, and then get that tab, but there is no openerTabId.

Is there another way to get the parent tab of a tab in a newly opened window?  Or is this an omission in the Chrome API?  If so, is it intentional?

I am using Chrome version 66.0.3359.139 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Looks like they simply didn't think of this specific use case. It's possible they don't track it even internally.

Comment: Did you ever find any solution to this problem?